# JS issues when deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, heroku, twitter-bootstrap

I am using rails 3.2.3 and have just deployed an app to heroku the same way as normal, though this time there seems to be an issue with my Jquery/javascript. My dropdowns don’t work, nor another plugin I have, yet my flexslider does (powered by JS). Looking in the console it seems as if all the js has been compiled into one file but I get this error

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

The app is at http://rocky-fortress-7573.herokuapp.com/ and maybe someone who is a little more clued up on JS could see what is going on? Everything works as it should locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is not included in your page. Add the following to your `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can i ask how you where able to determine that please?

Comment: i thought jquery rails took care of this for me?

Comment: Your edited version of jQuery on http://rocky-fortress-7573.herokuapp.com/assets/application-27c9dafc7da7393bd0ddd9fa078013c8.js is invalid. Keep your own functions (e.g., `is_valid_email()`) in the file, and add jQuery as I stated in my post.

Comment: thanks that worked, but still curious as to why jquery rails did not make the call?

Comment: `http://rocky-fortress-7573.herokuapp.com/assets/application-27c9dafc7da7393bd0ddd9fa078013c8.js` includes jQuery. However, your own functions, that use jQuery, are included first.